# Condicion If en vista, laravel

Tags: laravel, vistas, if

Buenas, tengo un listado de alumnos en una vista en la cual puedo colocar observaciones. Mi consulta es como crear un "if" para que me muestre el "agregar observacion" sólo si no tiene ninguna en la base de datos y en el caso de que ya tenga una observacion no mostrar el "agregar observacion"

[image: vista listado alumnos]

Estos son los campos en la base de datos:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('conductas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->enum('tipo',['Positiva','Negativa']);
        $table->string('descripcion');
        $table->date('fecha');

        $table->integer('id_alumno')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('id_alumno')->references('id')->on('alumnos');

        $table->integer('id_asignatura')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('id_asignatura')->references('id')->on('asignaturas');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Y mi vista :

```html
@section('content')
          
  <strong>Asignatura :   </strong>   <a>  {{$asignatura->nombre}}</a><br>
  <strong>Curso : </strong> <a>{{$asignatura->curso->nombre." / ".$asignatura->curso->tipo}}</a><br>
  <strong>Periodo :   </strong> <a>{{$asignatura->periodo." - ".$asignatura->created_at->year}}</a><br>
  <strong>Horario :    </strong> <a>{{$asignatura->horario}}</a><br><br>
 
  
 <table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
   <th>N°</th>
   <th>Rut</th>
   <th>Nombres</th>
   <th>Apellidos</th>
   <th>Correo</th>
   <th>Información</th>
   <th>Anotaciones</th> 
  </tr>

   @foreach ($alumnos as $alu)
    <tr>
     <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
     <td>{{ $alu->rut }}</td>
     <td>{{ $alu->nombre}}</td>
     <td>{{ $alu->apellido_paterno." ".$alu->apellido_materno}}</td>
     <td>{{ $alu->email}}</td>

     <td><a href="{{route('alumnos.show', $alu->id)}}" class="btn btn-info" ><span class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></span></a><br><br></td>
     
     <td><a href="{{URL('datos-profesor/veranotacion', $alu->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning" ><span class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"> </span></a>
     @if({{???}})
     <a href="{{URL('agregar/anotacion', array($alu->id, $asignatura->id ))}}" class="btn btn-danger" ><span class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>

    </tr>
   @endforeach

 </table>

@endsection
```

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Cómo obtienes las anotaciones del alumno?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Falta aclarar como obtienes las observaciones de los alumnos. Pero la respuesta seria:

```
@if (count($alu->observaciones) > 0)
    <a href="{{URL('agregar/anotacion', array($alu->id, $asignatura->id ))}}" class="btn btn-danger" ><span class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
@endif
```

Lo mas logico seria agregar una tabla "observacions" (observacion plurarizada) , te daria la posibilidad de agregar mas de 1 observacion y este codigo no tendria sentido. pero todo depende de tu implementacion

```
public function observaciones()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Observacion');
}
```

Comment: Hola disculpa la demora, a que te refieres con tabla observaciones plurarizada?? ya tengo la tabla observaciones (en mi caso su nombre es conductas) con la id del alumno y la id de la asignatura y sus relaciones correspondientes.

Comment: Entonces no te hagas problema, por ejemplo si tienes el Model "Conducta" si no le agregas el nombre de la tabla laravel considera que tu tabla se llama "Conductas", osea le agrega la "s", eso es plurarizar